# Decimal Format in python html mail content

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to send an Excel file as an attachment and in the mail body using Python. Everything is working fine.

But when I am converting Excel to HTML, numbers are appearing in decimal format. I want that to be integer format.

I have converted my DataFrame into HTML using this code

```
Churn_Invol_html = Churn_Invol.to_html(index=True, header=True, col_space=35, justify='center')
```

I expect the output should be without a decimal point, but in the HTML body there is a decimal point after every integer value.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `Churn_Invol` is a `pandas` dataframe. You can try to convert the column (or columns) with whole numbers to integers:

```
Churn_Invol.your_column_name = Churn_Invol.your_column_name.astype(np.int64)
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, convert it to integers and then to strings:

```
Churn_Invol.your_column_name = Churn_Invol.your_column_name.astype(np.int64)
Churn_Invol.your_column_name = Churn_Invol.your_column_name.astype(str)
```